# how to add a ProgressDialog to this code

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I would like to add a progress dialog to this code so when i click the button to load this activity it doesn't hang or give a black screen for a few seconds. also does it have to be in a Async task? i am willing to try it with a Async task only i just tryed a few times and i didnt get it to work

```
package net.thinkbin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class entertainment extends ListActivity {

private static final String TITLE = "Title";
private static final String AUTHOR = "Author";
private static final String VIEWS = "Views";
private static final String RATES = "Rates";
private static final String CONTENT = "Content";

JSONArray ideas = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder3);


    Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.TUTORIAL1"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.SHARE"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.MENU"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,   String>>();


    JSONObject json =     JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.thinkbin.net/include/api/index.php?cat=Entertainment&type=Views&i=10");

    try{

            ideas = json.getJSONArray("Ideas");

            // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < ideas.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = ideas.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String title = c.getString(TITLE);
            String author = c.getString(AUTHOR);
            String views = c.getString(VIEWS);
            String rates = c.getString(RATES);
            String content = c.getString(CONTENT);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TITLE, "Title: " + title);
            map.put(AUTHOR, "Author: " + author);
            map.put(VIEWS, "Views: " + views);
            map.put(RATES, "Rates: " + rates);
            map.put(CONTENT, content);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            mylist.add(map);


        }   


    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main2, 
                    new String[] { TITLE, AUTHOR, VIEWS, RATES, CONTENT }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item3, R.id.item4, R.id.item5 });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

 // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String Title2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)).getText().toString();
            String Author2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle)).getText().toString();
            String Content2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item5)).getText().toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), idea.class);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            in.putExtra(TITLE, Title2);
            in.putExtra(AUTHOR, Author2);
            in.putExtra(CONTENT, Content2);


            startActivity(in);


        }
    });

}                       
}
```

Comment: I would suggest your re-consider the AsyncTask, using the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() methods to show and hide your dialog since these methods are executed in the UI Thread there should be no problem what so ever.

Comment: sure ill want to try it only i hoped someone could edit my code a bit to get my started

Comment: or do i have to have my JSONfuncions class in an asynch task?

Comment: have you tried my answer @Jelle Breuer ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be `AsyncTask` you can make your `Activity implements Runnable` and then call `Thread.start(this)` from `onClick` putting your code in the `void run() {...}` of your `Activity`. Then you show dialog just before `Thread.start()` and kill the dialog when your task ends. Mind, though, when killing you will have to do `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { dismissDialog(YOUR_DLG)) }` because UI can be controlled only from the UI thread.

AsyncTask is nicer though.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code to display `ProgressDialog` ,

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(loginAct,"Process ", "please wait....",true,true);  
new Thread ( new Runnable() 
{      
      public void run()      
      {       
             // your code goes here      
      } 
}).start();   

Handler progressHandler = new Handler()   
{       
       public void handleMessage(Message msg1)       
       {           
             progDailog.dismiss();          
       }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem is to use async task.
Because Async task has few methods like

1. `onPreExecute()` - here you initialize you task.
2. `doInBackground()` - here you can have you network hit. i.e., fetching data from server.
3. `onPostExecute()` - here you handle the response received from the server and also the UI related task.

In addition to above it also have a method

`onProgressUpdate()` - which can be used to publish the progress of completed task.

This is the [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that show a sample about how use AsyncTask.